# How to wrap tf.cond function with keras.layers.Lambda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to define a custom layer in keras,but I can't find a way to warp tf.cond with layers.Lambda function

```py
        matches = tf.cond(
            tf.greater(N, 0),
            lambda: match_boxes(
                anchors, groundtruth_boxes,
                positives_threshold=positives_threshold,
                negatives_threshold=negatives_threshold,
                force_match_groundtruth=True
            ),
            lambda: only_background
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the body of your true function is very big, you could create a custom layer like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
    self.pred = kwargs.get('pred', False)

  def call(self, inputs):
    def true_fn(x):
      return x + 1.

    return tf.cond(self.pred,
                   true_fn=lambda: true_fn(inputs),
                   false_fn=lambda: tf.identity(inputs))
```

Testing:

```py
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=())

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.ones))
model.add(CustomLayer(pred=pred))

outputs = model(inputs)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(outputs.eval({inputs: [[1.]], pred: False})) # [[1.]]
  print(outputs.eval({inputs: [[1.]], pred: True})) # [[2.]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much,I have try to define a custom layer but didn't work ,thanks for giving a standard form.